# How to extract values from a list and add them into a new list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a data list like below. I need to extra all values after ":" and add those values into a new list. How can I do this?

**Sample data list**

```
list1= ['Company Name: PATRY PLC', 'Contact Name: Jony Deff', 'Company ID: 234567', 'CS ID: 236789', 'MI/MC:', 'Road Code:']
```

now I need to extract all the values after the colon(:) and recreate a new list like below. and also add null values for the empty strings for no values after the colon(:) like 'MI/MC:'.

**new list**
list2 = ['PATRY PLC', 'Jony Deff', '234567', '236789', 'null', 'null']

Comment: And what have you tried?  This is an easy task, done in a single line.

Comment: The string method "split" can help.

Comment: I tried the split method. it works fine. But I need to add null values to an empty string.`listdata = list(map(lambda x: x.split(':')[1], data))`

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` to split each item on `:`, and the `or` operator to turn the empty strings into `'null'`.

```
>>> list1= ['Company Name: PATRY PLC', 'Contact Name: Jony Deff', 'Company ID: 234567', 'CS ID: 236789', 'MI/MC:', 'Road Code:']
>>> [i.split(':')[1] or 'null' for i in list1]
[' PATRY PLC', ' Jony Deff', ' 234567', ' 236789', 'null', 'null']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['Company Name: PATRY PLC', 'Contact Name: Jony Deff', 'Company ID: 234567', 'CS ID: 236789', 'MI/MC:', 'Road Code:']

list2 = []

for x in list1:
    list2.append(x.split(':')[1])

print(list2)
```

[' PATRY PLC', ' Jony Deff', ' 234567', ' 236789', '', '']